# How to subtract one year from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want a button in windows forms application(C#) to display a exactly 1 year past time date and hour("specially hour")...

**Example:** if the date time now is `20 Aug 2013 2:15 pm` so when I click on the button, it will show me `20 Aug 2012 2:15 pm`... and opposite in 2nd button i.e from previous to current date time hour

Code I am using is just for yesterdays date

```
string result = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Hint: change `AddDays`

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
string result = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AddYears`:

```
string result = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

string convertback = DateTime.ParseExact(result, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddYears(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```